# have done something since

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I have known Tom since he lived next door.

The most common views of this sentence means

> I have known Tom from the day he moved in.

But someone argues that "live" is a non-continuity verb. So, here "since" means "because", and the sentence means

> I have known Tom because he lived next my door.

Comment: Hi! What is your question exactly?

Comment: @MorrisonBower, What does it exactly mean?